# .onChange() - Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type '()'

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to detect a change on my `@State` variables to update some text but I cannot get it to work because the `.onChange` modifier is throwing this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type '()'

```
struct CalcView: View {
    @State private var width = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                width += 1.0
            }, label: {
                Text("Increment width")
            })
        }
        .onChange(of: width) { // This line specifically 
            print("Width Changed")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closure you’re calling with the onChange modifier doesn’t take any arguments, but onChange wants to pass a Double to that closure. Try changing `.onChange(of: width) {` to this:

`.onChange(of: width) { newWidth in`

Answer (score 1):

To never get stuck in this again
start type method name,  then wait for the completion

[.onChange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEgTF.png)

the completion will popup with the details of the method
with the arguments

now you can see that .onChange() wants a value that conforms to the Equatable protocol [see more about Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable)

because "width" value type is Double type so it conforms to Equatable

```
.onChange(of: Equatable, perform: (Equatable) -> Void)
```

you can press enter to pass a closure in perform

```
 .onChange(of: width, perform: { newValue in   })
```

if you do not want to use newValue change it to _

```
.onChange(of: width, perform: { _ in   })
```

or you can even pass a function that has (Equatable) -> Void type

```
  .onChange(of: width, perform: performOnChangeAction)


func performOnChangeAction<T: Equatable>(newValue: T){
    print(newValue)
}
```

T is a generic type that conforms to Equatable learn  more about [generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)

Note that you cannot change newValue
[newValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAUUS.png)

you can always access and change width value with your conditions

```
  .onChange(of: width, perform: { newValue in
                        if newValue >= 10.0{return}
                        if newValue >= 20.0 {
                            widthError = true
                            width = 0.0
                        }
                    })
```

but that leads to more complex code in the view and the possibility of entering an infinite loop because every time you change width it will trigger .onChange()